# "as with" grammar and meaning in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, conjunctions

What is the meaning and grammar of "as with" in the following sentence:

> Symbolic logic is a mathematical model of deductive thought; **as with** other branches of mathematics it has grown beyond the circumstances of its birth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**From Oxford English Dictionary**

[image]

Your sentence -

> Symbolic logic is a mathematical model of deductive thought; **as with** other branches of mathematics it has grown beyond the circumstances of its birth.

From what we learned from OED note above we can re-write it as the following -

> As far as it (Symbolic logic) is with other branches of mathematics, it has grown beyond the circumstances of its birth.

Or simply -

> With other branches of mathematics it has grown beyond the circumstances of its birth.

You can also substitute **as with** with **like** in your original sentence.

Is that clear to you now?

Comment: as in- obsolete? Come on.

Answer (score 4):

[The "as with"] was probably located after a different sentence in a paragraph. For example the sentence before would be something like:

*Algebra is a very complex and complicated form of math.* **As with other branches of mathematics it has grown beyond the circumstances of its birth.**

Then in this case the "as with" means "the same thing applies to ......".

Comment: This does not make sense to me: replacing "the same thing applies to" with "as with" does not seem to communicate the right meaning and be grammatically correct: "Algebra is a very complex and complicated form of math. the same thing applies to other branches of mathematics it has grown beyond the circumstances of its birth"!!

Comment: The reason it is not grammatically correct is because you are supposed to use "as with" but because you did not understand that I gave a word that is similar.