# What is the meaning of "As with" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

What is the meaning of "As with" in the sentence, "As with all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it" ?

Does it mean "If we compare with all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it" ?

What does "as" and "with"  in this sentence mean?

I have encounted with "as with" in many sentences and I hardly know what it exactly means.

For example: 
She bought up as with the connivance of school.
As with all good catfights, there’s a boy involved.

Comment: A similar question:  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48158/as-with-grammar-and-meaning-in-a-sentence

Comment: What does " With prepositions, as has the general sense of as far as, so far as, and thus restricts or specially defines the reference of the preposition; e.g. as against, as between, as for..... " mean? I would be grateful if you could give us many many specific examples using easy words.

Comment: To be honest, even the explanation is mostly more abstract in meaning. So, there are many cases in which I do not understand the explanation. If you give a lot of example sentences with easy words along with explanations, it will be a great help to understand what exactly the explanation means.

Comment: The sentence structure used to explain the question is more complicated than the sentence structure of the question, and the words are more difficult. Obviously it would be a very good explanation. However, for a beginner in English, it can not be eaten like a rice cake in a picture.

Comment: I look up at Google before asking questions. However, I think that most of the answers to the questions must be clear, but the sentence structures and words used in the explanations are often more complex, so I can not be understood.

Comment: Even if the structure of explanation is complicated, if many examples of easy words are presented, it will be very helpful to understand what the meaning of the explanation is. In my experience, I have always been satisfied with the question through such explanations.

Answer (score 2):

"as with" = "just like with" or "as is true with"

The sentence you gave is talking about following your heart. It is saying that your intuition, rather than your rational mind, will let you know when you've found what you're looking for. "matters of the heart" refers to human emotions and how they affect our decisions.

So you could rephrase the original sentence as:

*Just like* any other time when you follow your heart, you'll know when you find it.

Or, more briefly:

*Just like with* all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it.

*As is true with* all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it.

*Just as it's true with* all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it.